# Is there a function like bumps.packbits in Python available in Go (make binary mumber from an array of int)?

Tags: go, bit

Is there a function like bumps.packbits() in Python available in Go (make a number from an array of int representing said number) ?

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html

for instance:

```
[1, 0] -> 0b10 
[0, 1] -> 0b01
```

The aim is to store large arrays of booleans in a compact way:

i.e. store `[]bool{true, false, ...}` as `0b10`...

and later manipulate them using bitwise operations on them

Here is an example from Labiew

https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/boolean_array_to_number/

One possibility (brute force) is as follows:

1. Convert each bool in the array to int, then int to string itoa()
2. Convert array of string to string using join()
3. Convert string to number of base 2

But I was wondering if there is not a more efficient way to carry out this conversion.

I’m trying to convert:

`{true, false, true} -> 0b101` , etc

Comment: You can implement one in 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The following method does the trick:

```
func B2i(b bool) int {
    if b {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

func Bools2BinInt(u []bool) int64 {
    v := []int{}
    // []bool to []int
    for _, item := range u {
        v = append(v, B2i(item))
    }
    // []int to []string
    w := []string{}
    for _, item := range v {
        w = append(w, strconv.Itoa(item))
    }
    // []string -> string
    x := strings.Join(w, "")
    // string to Int
    y, _ := strconv.ParseInt(x, 2, 32)
    return y
}
```